# Macro code based on multiple data validation?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I create macro code whereby the user needs to select a few of the input (data validation) and it will produce different result? In my case, the input are in PRODUCT page and consists of:

- product's name
- currency pair
- leverage
- bank

so, the outcome has to come out at TERMSHEET page.

My idea is to use Select case within Select case, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
With Worksheets("TERMSHEET")
   Select Case Target.text

        Case "Anytime Knock-In"

            Select Case Target.text
            Case "BUY"

                Select Case Target.text
                Case "YES"
                .Range("A7").Value = "This USD/MYR Anytime Knock-In Forward transaction allows client to protect against USD"
                .Range("A8").Value = "strengtening from the Strike Ratewhilst getting limited participation to USD weakening"
                .Range("A9").Value = "until Knock-In Barrier (which is monitored all the times is triggered. Once the Knock-In"
                .Range("A10").Value = "Barrier is triggerd, this structure will behave like a normal Formal contract and client"
                .Range("A11").Value = "no longer gets to participate to a weaker USD"

                End Select

            End Select

    End Select

End With
```

The input comes from the following `Cells`:

- "Anytime Knock-In" is in `Cell B9`
- "BUY" is in `Cell B19`
- "YES" is in `Cell B27`
- "USD/MYR" is in `Cell B25`

Comment: `Target.Text` cannot be *both* "Anytime Knock-In" *and* "YES" at the same time...  Where are you getting `Target` from ?

Comment: if it is for "Anytime Knock-In" , i'm getting Target from cell B9. Did I answer your question? So, how do I change it ?

Comment: If the `Target.Text` is `B9` and it has a value "Anytime Knock-In" during the run of the code it cannot change to "Buy" or "Yes" how have you setup the input for the `Worksheet` PRODUCT? (is it all in the same cell?)

Comment: Okay but my output is depends on these 4 input which is from data validations. How can I do that ? not in the same input. it is different.

Comment: Describe in your question in which `Cells` you place those values, from that I can give you an example.

Comment: Okay, So, here is the selected input:The "Anytime Knock-In" is in cell B9, "BUY" is in cell B19, "YES" is in cell B27 while "USD/MYR" is in cell B25.These are all the input based on data validations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `If statement`, this works better for single cases. You should use `Select Case` when you have multiple options for one `Variable`.

See code below, you just have to change the name of the `Workbook`:

```
Sub dataValidation()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsProduct As Worksheet
    Dim wsTermsheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks("Products.xlsx")
    Set wsProduct = wb.Worksheets("PRODUCT")
    Set wsTermsheet = wb.Worksheets("TERMSHEET")

    If wsProduct.Range("B9") = "Anytime Knock-In" Then
        If wsProduct.Range("B19") = "BUY" Then
            If wsProduct.Range("B27") = "YES" Then
                wsTermsheet.Range("A7").Value = "This USD/MYR Anytime Knock-In Forward transaction allows client to protect against USD"
                wsTermsheet.Range("A8").Value = "strengtening from the Strike Ratewhilst getting limited participation to USD weakening"
                wsTermsheet.Range("A9").Value = "until Knock-In Barrier (which is monitored all the times is triggered. Once the Knock-In"
                wsTermsheet.Range("A10").Value = "Barrier is triggerd, this structure will behave like a normal Formal contract and client"
                wsTermsheet.Range("A11").Value = "no longer gets to participate to a weaker USD"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have allot of different cases you would use `Select Case` as followed:

```
Sub dataValidation()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsProduct As Worksheet
    Dim wsTermsheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks("Products.xlsx")
    Set wsProduct = wb.Worksheets("PRODUCT")
    Set wsTermsheet = wb.Worksheets("TERMSHEET")

    Select Case wsProduct.Range("B9")

        Case Is = "Anytime Knock-In"

            Select Case wsProduct.Range("B19")

                Case Is = "BUY"

                    Select Case wsProduct.Range("B27")

                        Case Is = "YES"

                            wsTermsheet.Range("A7").Value = "This USD/MYR Anytime Knock-In Forward transaction allows client to protect against USD"
                            wsTermsheet.Range("A8").Value = "strengtening from the Strike Ratewhilst getting limited participation to USD weakening"
                            wsTermsheet.Range("A9").Value = "until Knock-In Barrier (which is monitored all the times is triggered. Once the Knock-In"
                            wsTermsheet.Range("A10").Value = "Barrier is triggerd, this structure will behave like a normal Formal contract and client"
                            wsTermsheet.Range("A11").Value = "no longer gets to participate to a weaker USD"
                        Case Is = "NO"
                            'do stuff
                    End Select

            End Select

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I'll try to look at it. One quick question, what's the different between Workbook and Worksheet ?

Comment: @Nur `Workbook` is the `Workbook` wherein you work (the name of how you saved you excel document), `Worksheet` is the sheets/tabs/pages inside the `Workbook` (`Sheet1`,`Sheet2` etc.)

Comment: Okay. I've seen both and have run both code but apparently I got compile error (user-defined type not defined) . I've changed the workbook to the name of my excel. it seems like the workbook line is wrong.

Comment: @Nur my bad, `Set wb = Workbooks("Products.xlsx")` <- see this, you just need to put the specific document type (.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm) behind the `Workbook` name. Updated my anwser

Comment: sorry for the late reply @DragonSamu. I run the code, luckily there is no error but unfortunately the outcome does not come out. It just blank. Just to confirm, the code needs to be placed at module right ? what do you think ?

Comment: @Nur I would suggest to use F8 and step through the process to see what happens, and yes it needs to be placed in a module

Comment: what do you mean by F8 and step ?

Comment: @Nur put your cursor in the `Sub` and press F8, this will start the code and you can step through the entire process when by pressing F8 everytime. This way you can see what happens at each step and if it actually process the code or not.

Comment: hey @DragonSamu, i've go throught all the codes as you suggested. and i noticed that the code just run until (
        Case Is = "Anytime Knock-In"). and then it skips to the (end if). For the rest select case, the code doesn't run through. Would you have any ideas on that cause I've spent like many days to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nur this means that in `Cell B9` there is no value`"Anytime Knock-In"` could you check/confirm this?

Comment: hey hey i got it solved already. It just the name that I put in the range is slightly different. Thank you so much brother :)

Comment: @Nur your welcome, don't forget to upvote and accept if the answer was useful :)